# how to dynamically allocate memory in mips and print the starting address

Tags: assembly, mips, dynamic-memory-allocation, qtspim

I need to ask the user for the number of bytes to allocate and then I need to print the starting address of that memory I just allocated in hexadecimal. Can anyone explain to me how to do that? Im using qtSpim. So far this is what I have.

```
.data
.globl memory
memory:
    .asciiz "number of bytes to allocate: "
.text
.globl main
main:
la      $a0, memory 
li      $v0, 4       #command to print string
syscall
li      $v0, 5        #command to read int
syscall
move    $a0, $v0
ori     $v0, $0, 9   #sbrk  
syscall
la      $a0, 0($v0)
ori     $v0, $0, 1      #command to print int
syscall
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Does it not print the string?  Not ask for an int?  Or do you not know what syscall allocates memory?

Comment: So I get that to dynamically allocate you use syscall 9 which is sbrk and it returns the start of the address in $v0, I need to print that address like: 0x00000000 a however when I print it I'm getting 9 integers instead of the 8 in hexadecimals.

Comment: The MARS simulator has a syscall for printing numbers in hexadecimal form, but QtSpim doesn't AFAIK. So you'll just have to write a function that converts the address into a string in hexadecimal form. It's really quite simple, considering that each hexadecimal digit corresponds to 4 bits.

Comment: Yeah i know MARS has that but I'm not allowed to use it :( how can you convert it to hexadecimal in mips? This is just a small part in the program I've been working on all weekend my brain is melting.

Comment: Well, like I said, each group of 4 bits corresponds a hexadecimal digit. So all you need is some masking and shifting in a loop.